# How to show/hide content based on user type in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a membership site where the user's membership level is identified upon login (`PRO=1, ELITE=2, PLATINUM=3, DIAMOND=4`), using mysql. There are a number of products sold, including memberships. I need to hide their membership as an order option. So I need to enclose the divs with some php code and if statements, based on their membership level.

Here is the basic html:

```
    <div><a href='#'>Order PRO Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>Order ELITE Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>Order PLATINUM Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>Order DIAMOND Membership</a></div>
```

If I am an ELITE Member, the only order options I should see are PLATINUM and DIAMOND.

Thanks much for your help.

Comment: Do you store the membership level in `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Seriously.... Please learn php first... because doing these kind of things is probably the most basic php.

Comment: Yes I am using $_SESSION

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
<?php
$member = $_SESSION['member'];

if($member == 1) {
    echo "<div><a href='#'>Order ELITE Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>Order PLATINUM Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>Order DIAMOND Membership</a></div>";
} elseif($member == 2) {
    echo "<div><a href='#'>Order PLATINUM Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>Order DIAMOND Membership</a></div>";
} elseif($member == 3) {
    echo "<div><a href='#'>Order DIAMOND Membership</a></div>";
}

?>
```

I can prove this works, if I do $member = 3; http://meowman.sytes.net/so/memberif/member3.php and http://meowman.sytes.net/so/memberif/member3.txt

Answer (score 0):

without knowing "how" you store the membership - this should give you a rough idea

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['user_level_status'] < 2) {

<div><a href='#'>Order PRO Membership</a></div>
<div><a href='#'>Order ELITE Membership</a></div>

<php } ?>

<div><a href='#'>Order PLATINUM Membership</a></div>
<div><a href='#'>Order DIAMOND Membership</a></div>
```

You can expand it from here - but this logic will guide you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the switch function like this:

```
<?php
$rank1 = mysql_query("SELET FROM tblname WHERE column='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['Username']) . "'");
$rank = mysql_result($rank1, 0, 'rank');

switch ($rank)
{
case 3:
  echo "<div><a href='#'>Order DIAMOND Membership</a></div>";
  break;

case 2:
  echo "<div><a href='#'>Order PLATINUM Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>Order DIAMOND Membership</a></div>";
  break;

case 1:
  echo "<div><a href='#'>Order ELITE Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>Order PLATINUM Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>Order DIAMOND Membership</a></div>";
  break;

default:
  echo "<div><a href='#'>Order PRO Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>Order ELITE Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>Order PLATINUM Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>Order DIAMOND Membership</a></div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Not a good piece of code. It should look like case 1: echo ELITE; case 2: echo PLATINUM; case 3: echo DIAMOND;